# is it possible to create a sprite class with out image?

Tags: python, image, sprite, livewires

I am trying to make a simon says game, and I don't need my User sprite to have image, but is it possible to make sprite with out calling image? like below? Or it is always required to call image whenever programmer creates a sprite?

```
#example


class User(games.Sprite):


    sound = games.load_sound("missile.wav")

    def __init__(self):

        self.life = 3
        self.action = None
        self.delay = 0
```

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: What good is a [sprite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_%28computer_graphics%29) without an image?

Comment: I wanted to get inputs from users through keyboard, but don't really need the image for users

Comment: What if you just didn't inherit from Sprite? I imagine then you wouldn't need an image.

Comment: A quick peek at the `livewires` source reveals that an `image` argument is required for a `sprite`. Surely there's some other way of getting user keyboard input. Have you tried Python's built-in `raw_input()` function?

Comment: @martineau _Have you tried Python's built-in raw_input() function?_ - Thats if he's using Python 2.x. In Python 3, that'd be `input()`.

Comment: @Mr.goosberry: All I know is what the OP put in their question.

Comment: I used livewires, and didn't user specific library

Comment: @martineau yes i know, but it's probably worth mentioning that there is difference in Python 3.x. Unless of course, there is something I'm missing in his code example that would suggest he is using Python 2.x

Comment: My game is like this. class Simon randomly choose an action in its dictionary, and user should do the proper action to get score. If user choose the wrong action, then user loses one life, and total of 3 loss will be game over. So the program requires immediate answers from user every second or frame therefore I needed to user update(self): function of Sprite.

Comment: @Martineau thank you for letting me know that livewires source reveals that an image argument is required for a sprite

Comment: @Tom: you're welcome. There are ways of reading single characters at a time in Python that work with both Unix (Linux), Windows, and maybe OS X, so they might be what you need. It's like the C `getche()` function. Search SO and I'm sure you can find out how. Hint: The Windows version uses the `msvcrt` module.